# display figure before new subsection, bot not on an own page

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I have multiple subsections, one with 3 subsequent figures

```
\subsection{Sometitle 1}
words words words...
```

3x

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/img}
  \caption{Desc.}
  \label{fig:img}
\end{figure}
```

then the next subsection

```
\subsection{Sometitle 2}
other words other words...
```

Two images take up a whole page, the third is displayed after the first few lines of the following subsection.. [image: like this]

How do I get to start the next subsection **after** the third figure, but not have the third figure on an own page?

Comment: Don't let your figure(s) float, i.i; put them in a è center` environment, rather than `table` and use `\captionof{figure}{…}`` (from the `caption` package. Altyernatively, use the `H` placement option (from `float`).

Comment: thank you very much for the comments, but since this is my first latex document, I don't quite know how to do this.

Comment: @Johannes_B: `\FloatBarrier`is defined in the `placeins` package.

Comment: This question was asked in the meantime over at [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=85038#p85038).

Answer (score 2):

Three solutions:

*With the `float` package:*

Add `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble, and write for your figure:

```
\begin{figure}[H}
\centering
\includegraphics[…]{…}
\caption{…}
\label{…}
\end{figure}
```

*With the `caption` package:*

Add `\usepackage{caption}` to your preamble, and write:

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[…]{…}
\captionof{figure}{…}
\label{…}
\end{minipage}
```

*With the `placeins` package:*

Add `\usepackage{placeins}` to your preamble, and write:

```
\FloatBarrier
\subsection{titleofsection 4.4.1}
```

However, beware this my cause unwanted white space on the page, especially for large figures, as LaTeX defines a limited amount of space for floats on a page. Naturally this may be overridden.

Comment: If you put the center-environment in a minipage, you prevent figure and caption to be splitted across pages.

Comment: I forgot that possibility, but you're right, thanks. I'll modify that part of the answer at once.

Comment: @Bernard ..I tried all of them.. but either I'm doing something wrong, or they don't work as intended. The minipage as well as the float figure {H} stuffed the third figure to the end of the page, so it continues where the paper ended. And the Floatbarrier put the third figure on its own page, then starting the next subsection on a new page..

Comment: There remains another possibility: replace the`minipage` environment with `center` (no `centering`, of course) and   `\captionof`. Question aside: are you sure the problem doesn't come from the size of your figures?

Comment: @apoc A minimal working example would be great.

Comment: I've replaced the minipage as you said with the center, which results again in a page with three figures, one only half visible due to the end of the page.. the size of my figures shouldn't be the problem I guess, or at least I can't see how.

@Johannes_B to provide a minimal working example is quite complicated for me since I'm using a template of our university, which includes so many \usepackage's and settings..

Comment: Try with `\includegraphics[scale=0.8}{…}` for all three graphics. If it works it's the figures size that's a problem. It also may happen that the bounding box of the figures is bigger than the actual figures, due to invisible white space. To check this point, put your figures in an `\fbox`, setting first `fboxsep` to 0pt.

Comment: with `\includegraphics[scale=0.8}{…}` the figures are way too big to even be displayed alone on a page. I was unable to put the figure/s in an fbox like this: `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{...figure...}`

Comment: You're supposed to write `\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=…]{your_figure}`. Anyway, now we know the problem comes from the figures size.

Comment: so resizing the pictures to a lower resolution might help?

Comment: You didn't even give us the optional argument of your `includegrahics` command. We are completely sticking into the dark here. We need more information.

Comment: @apoc: It's not a lower resolution, but a lower size. Of course it might help.

Comment: alright.. sorry if I don't provide the correct information to help me, I feel pretty lost.. I now managed to put the figures in \fbox'es but that didn't do much.. the figures do not have invisible white space.
I'll try to lower the size to get them all on one single page.. thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: You don't have to shrink the pictures (with the danger of making them worse). Includegraphics know keys like `width`, `height` or `scale`. If you set every of those pics to `height=.3\textheigt` you could be fine. Not sure tough.

Comment: @apoc Since you said that you are a beginner, you will need to read some introductory material ([LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)). That will make future questions clearer as well (if there are any left).

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you for your patience, I edited the images in GIMP, now they all fit on one page.. I'll read trough the novice guide, thank you very much! I underestimated the complexity and possibilities of latex..

Comment: It is like driving a car, or running a nuclear power plant. No need to learn how things work in the first place, or something bad may happen. It is the same with a word processor, you need to learn to use it in order to effectively handle it.