# Table appears always before conclusion section

Tags: tables

I draw a table, after the table I have a conclusion to write, but the conclusion comes always before the table while it must appear after it instead. 
Here is the code I used for the table:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l |l |l|}
......
\end{tabular}
\caption{Activity highlights }
\label{internshipheadlines}
\end{table}
```

For the conclusion:

```
\section{Conclusion}
```

How can I resolve this problem ? I even did `\newpage` after the table but it did not work.
**UPDATE:**

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| l |l |l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Date}&\textbf{Main task}&\textbf{Description}\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{March 3$^{\hbox{\tiny{rd}}}$ - March 07$^{\hbox{\tiny{th}}}$}&\multirow{2}{*}{Discovering HTTPCS}&I accustomed myself with HTTPCS  \\
    && scanner and what might be its needs.\\ 
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{March 10$^{\hbox{\tiny{rd}}}$ - April 04$^{\hbox{\tiny{th}}}$}&\multirow{4}{*}{CMS security assessment}&Security assessment of various CMS\\
    &&types to track their vulnerabilities \\
    && some of which were published.\\
    \hline

   \end{tabular}
   \caption{Activity highlights }
   \label{internshipheadlines}
   \end{table}
```

And the conclusion:

```
\section{Conclusion}
Once activity highlights has been done, the following third and fourth chapters will be fully dedicated to the two major tasks I fulfilled and that I choosed to talk about.
```

Comment: In order to influence the placement of floats, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31)

Comment: @Werner thank you, I tried the different symbols and their combination (`!ht` , for instance), but it could not help

Comment: So the assumption is that the table ends on the following page rather than where you placed it. Have you tried adding the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) to your preamble and using `[H]` instead? If not, then you should read the entire post I linked to.

Comment: @Werner Yes, you are right, I must read that interesting post. I will post the solution if I find it. Thank you

Comment: You can put a `\clearpage` before `\section{Conclusion}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you very much, it works even if i have a small trouble: the title of the page does not appear and its last row is a little bit cut, i will try to fix it. Thank you

Comment: Closely related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194672/display-figure-before-new-subsection-bot-not-on-an-own-page/194698#194698

Comment: @Bernard I used your solution but I get the table cut a little bit from the bottom (last row)

Comment: Which solution? I explain 3 methods. Is it possible to have a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: @Bernard I mean the one you gave me on that link, I read your answer for that person, you asked him to use float package and use `[H]` instead

Comment: Last row missing is quite strange. Could you post a short example, so that we can test?

Comment: @Bernard I updated.

Comment: To me works `[!h]` specifier.

Comment: @skpblack I tried your option even if it was the first one I used and it works ! I do not know why, however.

Comment: @begueradj: I have no problem with the H specifier and you code. No row is trimmed. As I re-wrote your table using tabularx, but it's a little off-question, is there a link where I could upload it so that you see what happens ?

Comment: @Bernard In reality I removed one line from 4 different rows so that it is why `[!h]` worked while it did not work before. I tried after your comment the `[H]` but it does not work. Unfortunately I can not post the full table because it is a part of a report I am not allowed to make public. I respect your attitude in that you are too curious and you have a scientific mind since you showed your will and interest to understand this problem and solve it. Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to put the following (from [placeins package](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/placeins/placeins-doc.pdf)) immediately prior to your conclusion section:

\FloatBarrier %keep floats out of the next section